# Why child object can not access inherited function from its parent in PHP?

Tags: php, inheritance

I have made a very basic type of my class and as mentioned in question Why child object can not access inherited function from its parent? I have added one new field and new constructor. `show_param()` is defined in parent class but I can not use it in child class?!

```
<?php
    class Test {
        private $age;
        private $fname;
        private $lname;

        public function __construct($age,$fname,$lname)
        {
            $this->age = $age;
            $this->fname = $fname;
            $this->lname = $lname;
            echo "A new constructor in " . __CLASS__ . ".<br />";
        }

        public function __destruct()
        {
            echo 'The class "', __CLASS__, '" was destroyed.<br />';
        }

        public function set_age($age)
        {
            $this->age = $age;
        }

        public function get_age()
        {
            return $this->age;
        }

        public function __toString()
        {
            return $this->fname." ".$this->lname;
        }

        public function show_param()
        {
            echo $this->age."<br />";
            echo $this->fname."<br />";
            echo $this->lname."<br />";
        }
    }

    //Child definition


    class T1 extends Test
    {
        private $level;
        public function __construct($age,$fname,$lname,$level)
        {
            $this->level = $level;
            $this->age = $age;
            $this->fname = $fname;
            $this->lname = $lname;
            echo "A child constructor in " . __CLASS__ . ".<br />";

        }
        public function get_level()
        {
            return $this->level;
        }
        public function set_level($level)
        {
            $this->level= $level;
        }

    }

    $a = new T1(23,"Bernard","Grey","Under");

    echo $a->show_param();

?>
```

Result:

A child constructor in T1.
A child constructor in T1.

The class "Test" was destroyed.
The class "Test" was destroyed.

Expected:

A child constructor in T1.
A child constructor in T1.
Bernard
Grey
23
The class "Test" was destroyed.
The class "Test" was destroyed.

Comment: What is the result you get? What result would you expect instead?

Comment: You've created setters for the age, name etc, but your not calling them in your T1 constructor.

Comment: You can't access the `private` data member by inheritance you should change it to `public/protected`

Comment: @BobFlemming I am actually calling them those data but they are private to the parent

Comment: As @Jitendra said I should change them to protected or use the parent constructor in child constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the parent`s constructor in class T1:

```
class T1 extends Test
    {
        private $level;
        public function __construct($age,$fname,$lname,$level)
        {
            parent::__construct($age,$fname,$lname);
            $this->level = $level;
            echo "A child constructor in " . __CLASS__ . ".<br />";

        }
        public function get_level()
        {
            return $this->level;
        }
        public function set_level($level)
        {
            $this->level= $level;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think it would be better to use the parents set_age() then add setters for the other parent properties too.

Comment: @KA_lin I think the other option is to make variables in parent class as protected. However this is also working...